# DataStax Python Cassandra Driver wrongly discovering Cassandra on localhost

Tags: python, cassandra, bokeh

I have this little university project and I have developed a simple Python app  with Bokeh frontend and Cassandra backend. I have been prototyping it and developing on a single Cassandra node and then scaled up to three nodes, one native, two virtualized. Therefore the development was on localhost, then I migrated to using a Host-only network named vboxnet0 with IP addresses:

- 192.168.56.1 for master
- 192.168.56.101/102 for slaves.

Cassandra version is 3.11.1

Bokeh server version is 0.12.10 (running on Tornado 4.4.3)

I have changed the code accordingly, so my app code begins with:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import dict_factory`

def pandas_factory(colnames, rows):
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)
auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='', password='')
cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['192.168.56.1'], port=9042, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect()
session.row_factory = pandas_factory
session.default_fetch_size = None
```

Cassandra is **not** running on localhost:

```
username@hostname:~> cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

And yet Python driver somehow thinks it discovered a Cassandra host on 127.0.0.1 and tries to connect to it:

```
username@hostname:~/Folder/subfolder> bokeh serve Appname > ~/bokeh.output
2017-11-22 19:24:49,230 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.10 (running on Tornado 4.4.3)
2017-11-22 19:24:49,233 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/Appname
2017-11-22 19:24:49,233 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 5819
2017-11-22 19:25:03,281 Using datacenter 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (via host '192.168.56.1'); if incorrect, please specify a local_dc to the constructor, or limit contact points to local cluster nodes
2017-11-22 19:25:03,281 New Cassandra host <Host: 127.0.0.1 datacenter1> discovered
2017-11-22 19:25:03,282 Found multiple hosts with the same rpc_address (127.0.0.1). Excluding peer 192.168.56.101
2017-11-22 19:25:03,368 Failed to create connection pool for new host 127.0.0.1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2343, in cassandra.cluster.Session.add_or_renew_pool.run_add_or_renew_pool (cassandra/cluster.c:44919)
  File "cassandra/pool.py", line 332, in cassandra.pool.HostConnection.__init__ (cassandra/pool.c:6757)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1119, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory (cassandra/cluster.c:16094)
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 330, in cassandra.connection.Connection.factory (cassandra/connection.c:5963)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cassandra/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 307, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 369, in cassandra.connection.Connection._connect_socket (cassandra/connection.c:7477)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused
2017-11-22 19:25:03,403 Host 127.0.0.1 has been marked down
2017-11-22 19:25:04,406 Error attempting to reconnect to 127.0.0.1, scheduling retry in 2.0 seconds: [Errno 111] Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused
2017-11-22 19:25:06,414 Error attempting to reconnect to 127.0.0.1, scheduling retry in 4.0 seconds: [Errno 111] Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused
2017-11-22 19:28:14,994 Error attempting to reconnect to 127.0.0.1, scheduling retry in 8.0 seconds: [Errno 111] Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused
2017-11-22 19:28:16,489 Host 127.0.0.1 may be up; will prepare queries and open connection pool
2017-11-22 19:28:16,808 Failed to create connection pool for new host 127.0.0.1:
```

And then it goes on and on. On the front it looks OK, the app works and 192.168.56.1 is queried correctly, but this is just  annoying that something is not right and I don't know if it's a bug or my own fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Cassandra does not use master/slave relationship. All nodes are equal in the sense that any of your nodes can act as coordinator. The coordinator is chosen based on the request and the client will pick the best coordinator to use. The coordinator will then coordinate with other nodes responsible for the data you're reading/writing and respond back to the client. The contact point that you're specifying in the client is just what it says, a contact point. It is only used to make an initial connection to the Cassandraa cluster. When that is done the client will keep a connection for each node in your Cassandra cluster (because any node is a potential coordinator for your request).

To answer your question. Your cassandra.yaml file is wrong.

```
2017-11-22 19:25:03,282 Found multiple hosts with the same rpc_address (127.0.0.1). Excluding peer 192.168.56.101
```

You need to set rpc_address to the address of the machine. Make sure to do this on each of your nodes in the cluster. Follow these steps to make sure you're not missing any configuration: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/configuring.html#main-runtime-properties

Also make sure to set the seed to the same ip/ips for all nodes. The seed is simply just the ip of one/many nodes in the cluster that the nodes will connect to when starting up. It's recommended to have two seeds per DC and it should be the same for all nodes.